# font download url is changing when i change page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fonts

So I'm having problems getting my fonts to load on all my pages, I've googled and googled and can't find anything but now think I've found the source of the problems
when i use `http://localhost:3000/` and `http://localhost:3000/recipes` it downloads my fonts from `http://localhost:3000/fonts/BebasNeue-Regular.woff2` but when I change the page to `http://localhost:3000/recipe/create` my font download location changes to `http://localhost:3000/recipe/fonts/BebasNeue-Regular.woff2` adding a `recipe/` in and so my fonts can't be found, how do I stop it adding `recipe` onto my location?

It is a react app with fonts in public folder and font face in a theme folder in the src

font face is

```
@font-face {
      font-family: 'BebasNeue';
      src: url(fonts/BebasNeue-Regular.woff2) format('woff2');
    }
```

Comment: `url('./fonts/fontname')` try this

Comment: Try putting a `/` at the start of the URL.  `/fonts/....`

Answer (score 0):

thanks @keith it worked with putting a `/` in

```
@font-face {
      font-family: 'BebasNeue';
      src: url(/fonts/BebasNeue-Regular.woff2) format('woff2');
    }
```